# Mysql select all courses and their chapters for each course

Tags: mysql

I have tables courses and chapters. Courses have many chapters.

Courses:

```
# course_id, name
'68', 'LIP v1'
'69', 'course 1'
'70', 'DLAO 1'
```

Chapters

```
# chapter_id, name, course_id
'109', 'Lean Integration Chapter 1', 68
'110', 'Lean Integration Chapter 2', 68
'111', 'Lean Integration Chapter 3', 68
'112', 'Lean Integration Chapter 1', 69
'113', 'Lean Integration Chapter 2', 69
'114', 'Lean Integration Chapter 3', 69
'115', 'Operational Execllence I', 70
'116', 'Operational Execllence II', 70
'117', 'Operational Execllence III', 70
'118', 'Operational Execllence IV', 70
```

Can I get with one query the list of all courses and for every course the list of the assigned chapters to that course?

Comment: Please clarify how the result should look like - usually, all result lines have the same columns

Comment: Did you try something already? maybe mysql join will do what you want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html